# Localizing a UWP application with multiple projects

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, localization, internationalization

In My UWP app I am maintaining my resources.resw in the Util class library.I have a button like this.

```
<Button
                    x:Name="BtnLogin"
                    x:Uid="LoginButton"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Margin="0,0,20,20"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Click="btn_Login_Click"
                    Style="{ThemeResource LoginButtonStyle}"
                    TabIndex="4" />
```

Button content is set as below in the resources.resw file.

```
<data name="LoginButton.Content"
    xml:space="preserve">
<value>Login</value>
```

This is the project structure

Place where the UI files maintaining

[image: Place where the UI files maintaining]

Place where the resources file maintaining

[image: Place where the resources file maintaining]

If the resources file exists in the same project the button content binds properly. When resource file in a different class library the content doesn't bind.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest

Binding from code behind is  not a proper answer.I need to bind from the xaml directly like below.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/windows10_development/windows10_development_localization.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this using

```
                    <Button
                    x:Name="BtnLogin"
                    x:Uid="/WinAppUtil/Resources/LoginButton"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Margin="0,0,20,20"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Click="btn_Login_Click"
                    Style="{ThemeResource LoginButtonStyle}"
                    TabIndex="4" />
```

Need to use ClassLibararyName/ResourceFileName/Resource when declaring the x:Uid